# How do you make people spawn with adventure mode and without the ability to do commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a Hunger Games map, so I want other players to not be able to break blocks or do commands.  I only want to let them open chests and attack the players.  How do you do that?

Comment: If you're only making a hunger games *map*, then there's no need to do this.

Comment: how about hungergames on a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the adventure gamemode its simply

`/gamemode 2` OR `/gamemode a` OR `/gamemode adventure`

Unfortunately you cannot disable commands for SPECIFIC players on LAN worlds and maps (e.g. Give op to Player123 but disable op for Player666) but you could use this to set kill anyone who changes to creative **repeatedly**:

`/kill @a[m=1]` (Put this on a repeating command block and it will kill them over and over and over again)

A little less punishing:

`/testfor @a[m=1]` attach a redstone comparator and a repeater and do this `/gamemode 2 @a` This will change the players gamemode to adventure as soon as he changes to creative

[image: A]

You can change the `gamemode` command to anything you want to punish the player with

Comment: There is no need to use `/testfor`, nor physical redstone logic. You only need one command: `/gamemode adventure @a[m=1]`. You should also use Chain command blocks, not multiple Repeating blocks.

Comment: @Skylinerw Wow! I did not know that. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: But how about you don't want people to go in creative and survival just adventure mode. What should we do

Comment: and also are the command blocks conditional or unconditional?

Comment: @user152014 I did not touch that setting

Comment: @user152014 And for the survival thing just attach the same testfor command except instead of m=1 its m=0. The number would be your game mode you want to test

Comment: 1.13 removed support for all abbreviations of gamemodes. 1.13 syntax for other commands: `/kill @a[gamemode=creative]`, `/gamemode adventure @a[gamemode=creative]`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to disable commands on a per player basis in a map. What you *could* do is somewhat detect the outcome of a player running a command and undo it. For example, you could have a marker armor stand follow each player to detect teleportation. Or you could undo gamemode changes using `\gamemode a @a[m=!2]` on a repeating command block.

#### Don't do that! It's bad practice.

Preventing cheating is *not* a map-maker's concern. If the map is played online on a public server, cheat-prevention can and should be handled *server-side* (e.g. by not giving `/op` to random players). If a player plays with friends and cheats against them, it's a social issue, not your concern. Now the only case left is your player playing alone. The way I see it, if a player *wants* to cheat your map he will, or he'll quit playing if he finds that he can't.

Now let's look at the other side of the coin. Imagine a regular player playing your map, with no intention to cheat whatsoever, having fun with your great map. An hour into the game, there's an unforseen bug somewhere in the maps commands (realistically, every map *will* have bugs). No biggie, a quick hop into creative should fix it...

Except this will happen:

> [Bob] This door mechanism seems to have broken... All well, that's Minecraft for you.
> [Bob] /gamemode c
> Bob set own gamemode to creative
> [@a] Set Bob's gamemode to adventure
> [Bob] What the...?
> [Bob] /gamemode c
> Bob set own gamemode to creative
> [@a] Set Bob's gamemode to adventure
> Bob quit the game.

Congratulations, you have now turned a happy player into a frustrated one. And you did it because of players who you didn't like, and whose opinion or happiness you never valued  in the first place. This is just about the *worst* thing you can wish for.

TL;DR: Don't take legitimate tools away from honest players to accommodate the dishonest ones.